# Displaying selected bindLabel and bindValue using ng-select in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect

In my Angular-15 project I have a list of countries consisting of code and name:

**component.ts:**

```
export class AppComponent {
  out = new EventEmitter();
  constructor() {}
  countries = [
    { code: 1, name: 'Ukrain' },
    { code: 2, name: 'Bulgaria' },
    { code: 3, name: 'France' },
    { code: 4, name: 'Algeria' },
    { code: 5, name: 'Belgium' },
  ];
}
```

**component.html:**

```
<ng-select [items]="countries"
           bindLabel="name"
           bindValue="code"
           [searchable]="false"
           [(ngModel)]="selectedCode">
</ng-select>

<br>
<small>Country Code: {{selectedCode | json}}</small>
<small>Country Name: {{selectedName | json}}</small>
```

I want to display bindLabel and bindValue of the selected countries into Country Code and Country Name respectively as shown in:

```
<small>Country Code: {{selectedCode | json}}</small>
<small>Country Name: {{selectedName | json}}</small>
```

I was only able to achieve that of Country Code using bindValue.

How do I achieve that of Country Name (bindLabel)?

Answer (score 0):

Using `ngModelChange` trigger the event and do it as below

```
<ng-select [items]="countries"
           bindLabel="name"
           bindValue="code"
           [searchable]="false"
           [(ngModel)]="selectedCode"
           (ngModelChange)="onCountryChange()">
</ng-select>

<br>
<small>Country Code: {{selectedCode | json}}</small>
<small>Country Name: {{selectedName | json}}</small>
```

ts

```
    countries = [
        { code: 1, name: 'Ukraine' },
        { code: 2, name: 'Bulgaria' },
        { code: 3, name: 'France' },
        { code: 4, name: 'Algeria' },
        { code: 5, name: 'Belgium' },
      ]

      selectedCode: number;
      selectedName: string;
      onCountryChange() {
        const selectedCountry = this.countries.find(
          (country) => country.code === this.selectedCode
        );
        this.selectedName = selectedCountry ? selectedCountry.name : '';
      }
```

Comment: How about if I want to populate it into input field      <input type="text" formControlName="Name">

Comment: You can use setValue to that form control `this.form.get('Name')?.setValue(this.selectedName);`. If this solve your purpose, please upvote and accept the answer.